# Android Lazylist with www.parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, lazylist

How can we achieve a lazylist like appearance for Images coming from Parse.com?

Normally, in a lazylist, the images would come via a temporary folder on the SDCard through a URL. That gives the "active and working" feel to the user.

Whereas, if we were to attach an Imageview directly with an image in Parse, then it keeps waiting till the complete image is loaded and only then will it show. This gives a "slow and break-in-service" kind of appearance to the user.

Any suggestions on what is the best approach - if we were to go for a Parse based data and image storage.